# How to preserve a drop shadow and outline when clipping?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, illustrator-effects

I’m trying to make an icon of the Australian flag overlayed onto a map of Australia for an Android app at work, but I cannot figure out how to get the drop shadow and outline to be clipped too.

Making the mask changes the colour of my drop shadow, and I lose the outline.

Here’s what it’s currently coming out as: notice the blue drop shadow and no white outline.

[image]

For reference, here’s an icon I did in a similar style. Notice how it has a black drop shadow and white outline.

[image]

How can I preserve the white outline and black drop shadow of my image when I apply the mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, what you want to do is apply the outline and drop shadow to the mask, not to the underlying image. The mask *is* your graphic. The image is just decorating the mask. The outline and drop shadow also decorate the mask.

Comment: This is how I understood it, too!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a drop shadow to your “clip group” object, but a stroke can't be applied to a mask or a group without also applying it to the children. To get the same effect, you could drill into the clip group (double click), select your clipping path, copy, then drill back out to the main view and hit Ctrl+F for Paste in Front, which will paste the exact same path right on top of your clip group. Apply your stroke to that path and it'll look like you have stroked the clip group. One caveat, though, is that the shadow won't take that stroke into account the way it normally would, but applying the shadow to your transparently-filled object would only look like the *stroke* is casting a shadow.

Comment: Or, another way to fake it would be to paste the clip path inside the clip group, and apply a stroke to the inside of the otherwise-transparent shape.